Send email when the appointment event appears
I'm trying to send an email that contains a calendar event in the body of the email rather than attached as an .ics file. I'm using the MailMessage class to send emails and I'm building the calendar event using the iCalendar format.
I followed the instructions to add the iCalendar event to the email body as text and set the email body's MIME type to "text/calendar". However, when the email is received, the calendar event still appears as an attachment rather than being rendered in the body of the email as a calendar event.
how is it coming:

how I would like it to look:

I'm using this code, what's wrong?
public async Task SendEmailAsync(MailRequest mailRequest)
{
    try
    {
        bool IsCancelled = false;
        bool IsRescheduled = false;
        int ReminderBeforeMinutes = 15; // Defina um valor padrão ou ajuste conforme necessário
        string TimeZoneId = "UTC"; // Use o identificador de fuso horário correto
        string EventCreatedDateTime = "2023-12-24 17:40 PM";
        string EventScheduledDateTime = "2023-12-28 08:40 PM";
        string EventScheduledEndDateTime = "2023-12-28 10:40 PM";

        DateTime eventCreatedDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(EventCreatedDateTime);
        DateTime eventScheduledDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(EventScheduledDateTime);
        DateTime eventScheduledEndDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(EventScheduledEndDateTime);

        TimeSpan span = eventScheduledDateTime.Subtract(eventCreatedDateTime);
        DateTime reminderDate = eventScheduledDateTime.AddDays(-2);

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(_mailSettings.Mail);
        mailMessage.Subject = mailRequest.Subject;

        if (_appSettings.Ambiente == "Producao")
        {
            mailMessage.To.Add(mailRequest.ToEmail);
        }
        else
        {
            mailMessage.To.Add(_mailSettings.Mail);
            mailMessage.Subject = $"Email de Teste - Ambiente: {_appSettings.Ambiente} - {mailRequest.Subject}";
        }

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
        str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//Schedule a Meeting");
        str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");

        if (IsCancelled)
        {
            mailMessage.Subject = "Cancelled: Meeting Invitation";
            str.AppendLine("METHOD:CANCEL");
            str.AppendLine("STATUS:CANCELLED");
        }
        else if (IsRescheduled)
        {
            mailMessage.Subject = "Rescheduled: Meeting Invitation";
            str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
            str.AppendLine("STATUS:CONFIRMED");
        }
        else
        {
            mailMessage.Subject = "Join this meeting on time";
            str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
            str.AppendLine("STATUS:CONFIRMED");
        }

        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");

        string customTimeZoneId = TimeZoneId;
        TimeZoneInfo customTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(customTimeZoneId);
        DateTime currentDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(eventScheduledDateTime, customTimeZone);

        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", currentDateTime));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", currentDateTime.AddMinutes(120))); // Assuming 2 hours meeting
        str.AppendLine("LOCATION:Hyderabad Gachibowli Gulshan Nagar Colony");
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", "WC5511"));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", mailMessage.Body));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", mailMessage.Body));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", mailMessage.Subject));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", mailMessage.From.Address));

        foreach (MailAddress attendee in mailMessage.To)
        {
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", attendee.DisplayName, attendee.Address));
        }

        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
        str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT" + ReminderBeforeMinutes + "M");
        str.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
        str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Hassan Reza");
        str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");

        str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
        str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

        SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpclient.Host = _mailSettings.Host;
        smtpclient.Port = _mailSettings.Port;
        smtpclient.EnableSsl = true; // Use SSL                
        smtpclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_mailSettings.Mail, _mailSettings.Password);            
      

        System.Net.Mime.ContentType contype = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
        if (IsCancelled)
            contype.Parameters.Add("method", "CANCEL");
        else
            contype.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");

        contype.Parameters.Add("name", "Calendar Meeting_Invitation.ics");
        
        AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), contype);
        mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);
        await smtpclient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {           
        throw ex;
    }
}

